# Rejected promise with SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0 when fetching raw file from Gitlab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gitlab

I'm trying to fetch a raw file from Gitlab repository, following official documentation.

The functions are the following:

```js
  methods: {
    async getProjects(url, method, payload) {
      const token = this.$store.getters.token
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Private-Token': token
      }

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      })
      return response.json()
    },
    [...]
    async addNewProject() {
      const payload = {
        "name": "newProjectName",
        "namespace_id": 12,
        "description": "description"
      }
      
      this.getProjects("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/", "POST", payload)
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data.id)
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e)
        })
        
      let rawFile = null
        try {
          rawFile = await JSON.parse(this.getProjects("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/files/readme%2Emd/raw?ref=master", "GET"))
        } catch (e) {
          rawFile = this.getProjects("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/files/readme%2Emd/raw?ref=master", "GET")
        }
      console.log(rawFile)
    }
  }
```

Logging the `rawFile` shows a pending Promise object with rejected state and the `SyntaxError` as in the title.

Is it possible that the raw format of the file is causing this error? If so, how to prevent it?

Comment: `raw` gets the actual file contents, right?  The readme.md file is probably not a json file

Comment: That's what I suspect as well. How to wrap the raw contents and process it as JSON?

Comment: actually...this is a bit of a mess. You need to `await` on your call to `getProjects` since it is an async function

Comment: and it looks like you are parsing the json twice.

Comment: and `gitlab.example.com` doesn't exist, so you won't get any results from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on.

- gitlab.example.com doesn't exist, so it's difficult to know what results you actually get
- You are passing the promise to `JSON.parse`. You need to use `await` or `then` to use the response:
- The end of your `getProjects` calls `response.json()` which will parse the json. You don't need to parse it again.

How about using:

```
let rawFile = await this.getProjects("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/files/readme%2Emd/raw?ref=master", "GET")
```

If the response is `json`, that would give you an object, but if the response is not json, you want to use `response.text()` instead. You'd need a different function:

```
async getTextFile(url) {
      const token = this.$store.getters.token
      const headers = {
        'Private-Token': token
      }

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
      })
      return response.text()
    }
```

then call it like this:

```
let rawFile = await this.getTextFile("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/files/readme%2Emd/raw?ref=master")
```